# some Kendo UI methods not working and are missed in MVC razor intellisence

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I am working on an ASP.net MVC project and am trying to create a Kendo Grid. the grid appears in browser and shows data but when I try to add some events, the intellisence doesn't show for example .Sort() (and .Group(), .Page(), .Filter() ...) in Events Method and if I try to use them I get this error :

> 'GridEventBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Sort' and no extension method 'Sort' accepting a first argument of type 'GridEventBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

this is the view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<BekProject.Models.UserGroup>()
    .Name("UserGroupGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Title("Product Name");
        columns.Bound(c => c.CreationDate).Title("Product Name");
    })
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable.ButtonCount(5))
    .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(false))
    .Filterable()
    .Editable()
    .Groupable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable
        .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple)
        .Type(GridSelectionType.Cell)
    )
    .Events(events => events
        .Change("onChange")
        .DataBound("onDataBound")
        .DataBinding("onDataBinding")
        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! .sort is highlighted as error
        .Sort("onSorting")
        .Group("onGrouping")
        .Page("onPaging")
        .Filter("onFiltering")
    )
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Events(events => events.Error("grid_errorHandler"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("UserGroups_Read", "UserGroupGrid"))
    )
)
```

controller:

```
public class UserGroupGridController : Controller
{
    private MainContext db = new MainContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult UserGroups_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        IQueryable<UserGroup> usergroups = db.UserGroups;
        DataSourceResult result = usergroups.ToDataSourceResult(request, userGroup => new {
            UserGroupId = userGroup.UserGroupId,
            Name = userGroup.Name,
            CreationDate = userGroup.CreationDate
        });

        return Json(result);
    }

    public ActionResult Events()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Sorting()
    {
        return View();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

anybody knows how I can fix it?

Comment: What version of controls are you using? [This Kendo demo with sorting](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/events) seems to work as expected, using version 2017.2.504. Additionally, I think you're `Sorting` function needs to be declared in JS.

Comment: I am using this version: Telerik.Kendo.UI.Complete.2016.2.607

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16607910/6224482) SO question aswell, seem to be additional scripts required to use `Sort`?

Comment: You're first point was right. I updated it to telerik.ui.for.aspnetmvc.2017.2.504 and it's working now. thank you @Sandman

Comment: No problem.. :)

Comment: I can mark it as correct answer, if you think you should write it as an answer @Sandman

Comment: Sure thing, thanks :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure the following:

- You are using the same version as [this Kendo demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/events) - 2017.2.504.
- All required scripts are included ([`kendo.aspnetmvc.js` and `kendo.web.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16607910/6224482))